# PhantomJS not rendering all of page even with a few seconds delay

Tags: javascript, linux, phantomjs

I am using my linux box to try and periodically download my local skateboard park's webpage and search for whether there are free skate-school lessons available.

I'm currently falling at the first hurdle as I am only getting a partially rendered page. The crucial dynamic content is missing.

I'm using a bash command to get an html file:

```
$ phantomjs get_page.js [my local skateboard park's URL] > [a_file.html]
```

My save_page.js looks like this:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(system.args[1], function()
{
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
}, 10000);
});
```

There is a ten second delay in there - but it also fails to load the whole page with a 3 or 5 second delay.

Comment: Whats the URL? You script seems to work with google.com here locally.

Answer (score 1):

Your example script seems to work fine here.

Added some extra loggin:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log(system.args[1]);

page.open(system.args[1], function(status) {
    console.log(status);
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
    }   , 10000);
});
```

Output for `node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs get_page.js http://www.google.com/ > test.html`:

```
http://www.google.com/
success
<!DOCTYPE html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"...
```

What is your URL and output? if you add this extra console.logs?

Comment: My HTML file is now blank apart from Status: success... URL:http://houseofvanslondon.com/book-skate-session   Incidentally the content appears if I use another phantom.js example where the page gets rendered to .png but that is not what I am trying to acheive.

Comment: Weird the same code works here i get: http://houseofvanslondon.com/book-skate-session
success
<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>Book a Skate or BMX Session - House of Vans London</title>...

Comment: can u wget or curl the url from the command-line? maybe it is a network or proxy issue, dont really know. Your code seems good. I do see another hurdle after you fixed this one. That is that the skate dates are loaded into in iFrame. Maybe it is easier to write a selenium-webdriver script in javascript using the new chrome-driver --headless argument which has been added in Chrome version 59 (current version is 60) https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Comment: it's the skate dates I'm after... they are the bit that is absent from the finished HTML file. I'm on lubuntu on an old 32bit machine so I don't think I can get chrome 59

Comment: No only 64bit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484622/how-to-get-full-interpreted-html-source-with-iframes-in-phantomjs maybe it helps. Never tried it, so your own your own :)

Comment: Thanks for your help - I wonder how it renders the whole page to .png corretly (including skate times) if I run a diffrent script `var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://houseofvanslondon.com/book-skate-session', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  if(status === "success") {
    page.render('example.png');
  }
  phantom.exit();
});`

Comment: it does render the iframe visually, but as it is a different page in a page it is not included in content of that main page.

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal - I think the iframe with PhantomJS matter would make an excellent canonical question and answer. Do you want to add it?

Comment: @KatePaulk No, PhantomJS is dead, the webkit engine hasnt been updated in years. Doesnt support cross-domain iframes sources. The maintainer has stepped down and he suggest to use Chrome headless instead :) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal - well, that's a shame. PhantomJS was a useful tool. Hopefully Chrome headless will serve as a viable replacement.